# java + print vertical BAR

Tags: java

I start today to write my first java program
I write java program that count capital letters from args[0]
and display it by number

```
     charCountA = args[0].replaceAll("[^A]", "").length();
     charCountB = args[0].replaceAll("[^B]", "").length();
     charCountC = args[0].replaceAll("[^C]", "").length();

               System.out.println("A   " + charCountA );
               System.out.println("B   " + charCountB );
               System.out.println("C   " + charCountC );
```

if args[0]=ABBCCC
then the program print

```
    A 1
```

my question  how to display the charCountA and other cahrCountB/C.... by vertical bar 
for example

```
 charCountA=1 then will print --> A  #
 charCountA=2 then will print --> A  ##
 charCountA=3 then will print --> A  ###
 charCountA=3 then will print --> A  ####
```

and so on

Comment: Bar should be vertical, or horizontal (as in your example)?

Comment: Ok, but you should know that it is horizontal, not vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `print` instead of `println` to write part of the line. In your case, you can do `System.out.print("A  ")` to append `#` to it later.
2. You can use `for` operator to loop some specific amount of iterations doing same action each iteration. In your case, you would need something like: `for (int i=0;i<charCountA;i = i + 1)`. You can read more about for loop here: [Java tutorials: The for Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
3. In each iteration you would need to output **one** # sign. So if repeated charCountA times - you would get a horizontal bar. So simply insert `System.out.print("#")` into the loop body.
4. After writing the bar, you would need to go to the new line to print next letter. You can do that by writing `System.out.println()` without any parameters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I write this: System.out.print("A " ); for (int i=0;i<charCountA;i = i + 1) { System.out.print("#"); } System.out.println("");                , but I want to create from that function to call function evry time I need how to do that?

Comment: hi MAx , littlie difficult because I new , can you please give example?

Comment: This is example of function: `void someFunction(int someParam) { System.out.println(someParam); }`. This is example of calling that function: `someFunction(10)`

Comment: but when I write someFunction(10) , I get delete 10 token ?